# Negative look ahead

Tags: regex, grep

I want to match a line when `foo` is not followed by a `bar`, e.g.

`foo bar` <-- not match

`foo 123` <-- match

I use the following regex

```
echo 'foo bar'  | grep -P 'foo.*(?!bar)'
```

The above regex should not be matched, but it is matched in fact.

Any reason?

Comment: What version of grep on what operating system?

Comment: I am using GNU grep 2.5.4 on Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the regex as follows:

```
'foo(?!.*bar).*'
```

Output:

```
$ echo 'foo bar'  | grep -P 'foo(?!.*bar).*'
$ echo 'foo 123'  | grep -P 'foo(?!.*bar).*'
foo 123
```

Comment: The `.*` at the end is not necessary

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be worked, can you also explain on the regex?

Comment: @TomFenech: You're right, but if it is excluded, then only `foo` will be highlighted in the output.

Comment: @Ryan: In your regex, `.*` greedily matches everything until the end of the string, including `bar`. I just changed the regex to include a `.*` in the lookahead, so it checks each position to see if it is *not* followed by `bar`. As Tom Fenech commented above, the `.*` at the end is optional; you can remove it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why make complicated regex, use `awk`

```
awk '/foo/ && !/foo bar/' file
```

If there are more distance between `foo` and `bar`

```
awk '/foo/ && !/foo.*bar/' file
```